# Optimal Control Of Stochastic Differential Equations

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, optimal-control

### Background :

I have studied mathematics and have a good knowledge of stochastic processes and a fairly good knowledge of stochastic calculus (for this I am currently reading [Brownian Motions, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319310886), which I find a well-written introduction to the subject.

### Type Of Problem I would like to solve :

I'm interested in theoretical inventory theory. The general idea is the following: we have a shop which sells a certain product, demand arrives according to some (continuous) stochastic process. As the demand depletes the inventory of the shop, the shop has to order new supplies, these supplies then arrive after some time. As long as the shop has supplies a holding cost of $h$ per unit is incurred and if the shop runs out of stock, it gets a negative stock with a backlog cost $b$ per backlogged unit.

We would now like to descibe which ordering policy would be optimal for this shop (for this example this problem has of course already been solved, but I would like to solve it for similar problems).

See for example the [Inventory Management with Stochastic Lead Times](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.2014.0671).

### Needed Reference :

I have been looking around on how to tackle this problem and it seems like this is a ''stochastic control'' problem. For this I found the book [stochastic controls: Hamiltonian systems and HJB equations](https://www.amazon.es/Stochastic-Controls-Hamiltonian-Equations-Probability/dp/0387987231), which at first sight looks pretty good. But as I am just getting into the problem, I would like to hear from you other (better?) references.

There are a lot of books on inventory theory but they all seem very "low level" to me, not dealing with anything like stochastic differential equations etc.

Comment: You could discretize (isn't the inventory already discrete?) And apply [stochastic dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dynamic_programming).

Comment: Hi: I'm pretty sure that, for your particular problem, your more likely to find relevant work in text-books having to do with operations-research or industrial engineering. You refer to the well known problem ( and I agree. I remember that type of problem ) so doesn't the literature on that problem, point to other related research ?  Back in the 80's-90's, there was a series of I.E type textbooks each having  to do with scheduling, inventory, facilties layout etc. I'll see if I can find out specifically what I'm talking about. We're talking 25-30 years ago !!!!!

Comment: This book is not part of that series but David Simchi Levi is well known in this field. But I don't think he deals with stochastic differential equations. As the other person mentioned,  using SDE might not be the way to go. https://www.amazon.com/Logic-Logistics-Algorithms-Applications-Engineering/dp/0387949216/ref=sr_1_9?crid=2P0FPWYBG7J2F&keywords=david+simchi+levi&qid=1703451822&sprefix=david+simchi+levi%2Caps%2C80&sr=8-9